# store kit subscription sandbox time seems longer than documented

Tags: ios, storekit, subscriptions

I am currently testing Auto Renewing Subscriptions in the StoreKit sandbox environment. It's seems to all be working, except the expiration times are hours in stead of minutes. Has anyone else ran in to this problem. The 1 Month subscription is lasting about 12 hours not the 5 minutes documented

timeLeft on purchase below: 11.8143773738874

[expires_date_ms: 1446002796000, 
purchase_date_pst: 2015-10-27 08:26:36 America/Los_Angeles,
purchase_date_ms: 1445959596000, 
web_order_line_item_id: 1000000030764855, 
expires_date_pst: 2015-10-27 20:26:36 America/Los_Angeles, 
transaction_id: 1000000177540714, 
is_trial_period: false, 
product_id: XXXXXXXXXX.1_month_test_1, 
purchase_date: 2015-10-27 15:26:36 Etc/GMT, 
**expires_date: 2015-10-28 03:26:36 Etc/GMT**, 
**original_purchase_date: 2015-10-27 15:26:36 Etc/GMT**, original_transaction_id: 1000000177540714, 
quantity: 1, 
original_purchase_date_ms: 1445959596000, 
original_purchase_date_pst: 2015-10-27 08:26:36 America/Los_Angeles]

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing. Basically for me they are auto-renewing every day. And I keep receiving payment every day since 2 months.

I posted on Apple developer but no answer.

Comment: I'm still having issues. I'll keep you posted if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I was using the email address associated with the iTunes connect account when logging in to the store in sandbox mode. What I needed to do was create a new sandbox user (I just made up any old email address and password) and use that email and password when you log in to the store  sandbox.
It worked!